# Java Drawing an Arc between two given points

Tags: java, math, drawing

say i have two points (x,y) (10,10) and (100,100) how would i be able to calculate the width, height, startAngle and arcAngle, to draw an arc between those two points? please note that this is **NOT** a homework exercise.

Comment: Well, you would start by doing the necessary calculations

Comment: Do you feel like this belongs in StackOverflow? Or, that it has any relevance to Java?

Comment: since i'm asking how to calculate the parameters of the java.awt.graphics#drawArc method, i believe it does. also, if you aren't going to do anything but making obvious statements, why bother writing comments?

Comment: Please try to code it **then** come on StackOverflow if you can’t do it. This is not a code-my-problem-for-free service.

Comment: @bfontaine i never asked for people to "code-my-problem-for-free" i asked for help to calculate parameters of a java method

Comment: @FrankK you asked them to do something you haven’t tried yourself for you. Please try it yourself *then* ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a circular arc, there are many.
Any point on the perpendicular bisector of the two points (that is the line through the midpoint at right angles to the line through the points) is the centre of a circle that passes through the two points.